# Leaflet how move to search location?

Tags: leaflet

i tried leaflet search control. Searching works great, i can see list with my  points names, but when I want search it, it does not work, not move to search point. My JSON data are points.   `    var data = us_states;

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 5, center: new L.latLng([37.8, 16]) });

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        style: function(feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color };
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.OBJECTID +'</h4>');
        }
    });

map.addLayer(featuresLayer);

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: featuresLayer,
    propertyName: 'OBJECTID',
    marker: false,
    moveToLocation: function(latlng, OBJECTID, map) {

        var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
        map.setView(latlng, zoom); // access the zoom
    }
});

searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {

    //console.log('search:locationfound', );

    //map.removeLayer(this._markerSearch)`
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help. I manually figured out a zoom level that I wanted it to go  to and set it in the control, after all it's just a marker. I would do it different if it was a polygon.

```
    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: bbTeam,                //layer name to search
    propertyName: 'Name',         //Search field
    marker: false,
    moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
        map.setView(latlng, 7);    // set the zoom
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it is still not working.  My JSON are points. It  looks that searching is ok https://ibb.co/eFSxfQ,  but after enter(click)  map is not move, not zoom  nothing,  i am very Frustrated... I have spant many hours, for this. I is for my school project.

Comment: moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
 console.log(latlng);  
        map.setView(latlng, 14); 
    }
})   //This should show your getting lat/long coordinates and from there a setview should work.

Comment: great excellent, it is working :)  can you give one more advice, it it move to location, but  i want mark serach point, circle around marker, or change color, can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need these two code blocks, I have it set if you click on a marker to put a red circle at the base of the marker. And if you click another marker to remove the first circle.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
            // get coordinates from GeoJSON
            var coords = e.target.feature.geometry.coordinates
            //pass coords to function to create marker.
            onMapClick(coords)

//////////////////////////////////          


// click marker
  var clickmark;

  // When you click on a marker, it calls the onMapClick function and passes the layers coordinates.
  // I grab the coords which are X,Y, and I need to flip them to latLng for a marker, 

  function onMapClick(coords) {

        var thecoords = coords.toString().split(',');
        var lat = thecoords[1];
        var lng = thecoords[0];
        //if prior marker exists, remove it.
        if (clickmark != undefined) {
          map.removeLayer(clickmark);
        };

         clickmark = L.circleMarker([lat,lng],{
            radius: 10,
            color: "#red",
            fillColor:  "red",
            fillOpacity: 0.8}
         ).addTo(map);
    }
// end of code for click marker.
```